# Objective C Accessing var in Initial View Controller of Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Using:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

But I need to set a BOOL in the initial viewController for that story board.

I have BOOL declared in the .h and an if statement is dependent on it:

```
if (_boolIsTrue) {
    FirstView *firstView = (FirstView *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first_view"];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[firstView] animated:NO];
}
else {
    SecondView *secondView = (SecondView *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second_view"];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[secondView] animated:NO];
}
```

When I try to access it with something like:

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc =[storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
```

vc does not give me access to the BOOL.

Not sure what it is that I am not understanding about ViewControllers and Storyboards, but I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks

EDIT AFTER SOLUTION:
Wain was exactly right!

Here's the exact working code since my gaps spanned a couple different concepts. In case it helps someone else:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@“MyStoryBoard” bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
InitialLockSetupViewController *vc = nav.viewControllers.lastObject;
vc.isBoolTrue = YES;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

So you have to get the View Controller with the correct type in order to access the var.  BUT if it's not set as the initial view controller in the storyboard you have to get it as the root (0-th) view controller on the stack.  THEN you have to remember to push the nav controller NOT the view controller.

Thanks again Wain.  This was a good lesson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply not understanding that the compiler needs to know the class type. Currently you're telling the compiler that the class is `UIViewController` and it obviously doesn't have your custom property. You need to set the class to your custom one, like:

```
MyViewController *vc = [storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Also, make sure that you don't call `instantiateInitialViewController` more than once or you'll have multiple copies of the same class and might use the wrong one...

Comment: Hrm.  I'm still missing something:

    UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                InitialViewController *vc = [storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
    vc.boolIsTrue = YES;

doesn't work.
Was that what you were intending?

Comment: Compile error? Which line? What is the message? InitialViewController.h has the `boolIsTrue` property?

Comment: HA!  Fat fingers!  It can access it now.  But I get: [UINavigationController setIsBoolTrue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x127d26730

Comment: code:

UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@“MyStoryBoard” bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
                [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
                
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@“MyStoryBoard” bundle:nil];
                InitialLockSetupViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
                vc2.isBoolTrue = YES;
            });

Comment: Ok, so your initial view controller is really a navigation controller, so it should be `UINavigationController *nvc = [storyboard ...]; MyViewController *vc = mvc.topViewController;`

Comment: YES!  Thank you!  Accepting the answer.  Thank you for the education as well!  Helped my understanding a metric ton!